# GCM messages not receiving in some devices sent by server to google?

Tags: android, https, google-cloud-messaging

We have implemented GCM to show notifications in android application but only some messages not receiving in devices sent by server to google? Server is sending messages without collapse_key so every message should reach in device without collapsed. Please suggest me to proceed further.

Thanks

Receiver code is below:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

service code is below:

```
 public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

     NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                //sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                //sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
               generateNotification(this, name, id, message);
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Manifest file is below

```
<permission
    android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/> 
<receiver  android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

Comment: provide more information. this is vague.

Comment: I have provided more information of my code above.

Comment: since you are receiving some messages, i believe you have completed registration, got the gcm reg id for the device and you are sending the gcm from your server or localhost. just one thing also include the http response of your server

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Google account in that device (Settings -> Accounts -> Google). So please check whether it's  logged with Google or not :)

Comment: yes, gmail account is active in all of the devices and able to access play store also.